# Aumentar o valor da recompensa caso ninguém a responda de forma satisfatória?

Tags: suporte, recompensa

Há como aumentar o valor da recompensa paga por uma resposta?

Recentemente adicionei uma recompensa a uma pergunta minha porém caso ninguém a responda efetivamente eu poderia subir a recompensa? Ou poderia criar uma pergunta semelhante e adicionar uma recompensa maior?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

De acordo com uma [resposta para uma pergunta muito similar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26731/raise-bounty-later#comment450024_54291) no Meta Stack Overflow EN:

> http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/
>
> Você pode adicionar uma nova recompensa à sua pergunta -- de um valor
>   mais alto se necessário -- caso a primeira recompensa não alcance os
>   resultados que você desejava.

**Original:**

> http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/
>
> You can now open another bounty on your question -- at a higher value
>   if necessary -- if the first bounty didn't get the results you wanted.

O detalhe a ser destacado é que você não pode **aumentar** a recompensa, e sim colocar uma **nova**, ou seja, se a primeira recompensa foi de 50 pontos e a segunda de 100, você terá gasto no total 150 pontos.

Como uma dica, acho válido destacar que simplesmente adicionar uma nova recompensa provavelmente não ajudará muito, a não ser que o valor seja muito alto, afinal, a maioria das perguntas já são respondidas sem recompensa, e se mesmo em destaque não houve resposta, a dificuldade deve estar na pergunta, e não em sua visualização. Talvez valha a pena voltar à pergunta antes e tentar simplificar o caso, incluir mais detalhes ou outras informações que a tornem mais atrativa.